# is there a way to measure Swift's performance without building UI on iPhone with Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to measure performance of different swift libraries without writing UI on iPhone. There are many examples of Swift/UI examples that are normally, multi-threaded in nature. So what I want to measure is raw performance without gui overhead, if possible. And the output can we printed into the Xcode 11 console window in debugger, for example. Could you please kindly point me where I could find such sample code ? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Build a macOS commandline tool as the wrapper for your measurements.

Comment: will macOS commandline tool run on iphone ?

Comment: No, but since you're not using any UI and simply comparing raw performance, that shouldn't matter. If you need to run on iPhone, you will have to build a minimum app wrapper, e.g. from the "single page app" template.

Comment: and what function do I need to use to print/redirect to Xcode console if I go with the single page app option ?

Comment: NSLog() or print() will work just fine

Comment: I will look into this, Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you asking maybe how to benchmark functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to measure the time of a sum of numbers

```
let numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6]

func showBenchmarkTime(title:String, operation:()->()) {

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    operation()

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime

    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

showBenchmarkTime(title: "sum an array of numbers") {

    print(numbersArray.reduce(0, +))
}
```